# How do I make a picker reside inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

How can I make the UIPicker so that it appears inside the cell and the user scrolls up or down the items and you can only see the current item in the picker "window"?

Im not even sure its a UIPicker.

Comment: Do you mean something like that http://www.wannabegeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/datepicker1.png ?
Sorry, because I couldn't understand your question?

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi yeah that will work! :)  Is that from your blog or something?

Comment: No I have searched for you :) If it works I will put it as an answer please let me know.